# Is $\sf NF(U)$ interpretable in $\sf NF(U)-0$?

Tags: lo.logic, new-foundations

It is known that in $\sf ZFC$ related theories one can remove the the empty set axiom and foundation, stipulate that all sets are nonempty, axiomatize replacement and separation in such a manner that the resulting set must be non-empty, and rephrase Infinity by stipulating existence of a set that has an injection to a proper subset of it; and yet we still get to interpret the empty set and thus full $\sf ZFC$.

> Can a similar move be done with $\sf NF(U) $?

That is, change stratified comprehension as to require the defining formula holding of at least one object, stipulate that all sets are nonempty, and stipulate that there are more than one set. To get $\sf NFU$ like theory, we weaken Extensionality about some particular nonempty set like for example the universe $V$, and add an axiom of Infinity. I call those systems $\sf NF(U)-0$.

> Can $\sf NF(U) -0$ interpret $\sf NF(U)$?